# How to confrim the node exist or not between two jobs information?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

In my project, I have pbs job information file: JobInfofile

Some content of JobInfofile is like:

```
1089608.mu01            maad-zhangy cal-l    ct+gd+sdg-160FWH  25025    22    528       --   72:00:00 R  07:20:52
   cu222/0-23+cu206/0-23+cu191/0-23+cu186/0-23+cu175/0-23+cu163/0-23+cu158/0-23
   +cu142/0-23+cu125/0-23+cu124/0-23+cu118/0-23+cu116/0-23+cu115/0-23
   +cu114/0-23+cu113/0-23+cu112/0-23+cu111/0-23+cu110/0-23+cu109/0-23
   +cu108/0-23+cu089/0-23+cu047/0-23
1090225.mu01            phy-xiel    cal-l    multijobs.pbs     21540    20    480       --   72:00:00 R  46:00:54
   cu198/0-23+cu144/0-23+cu123/0-23+cu122/0-23+cu121/0-23+cu120/0-23+cu119/0-23
   +cu098/0-23+cu095/0-23+cu094/0-23+cu092/0-23+cu091/0-23+cu087/0-23
   +cu086/0-23+cu085/0-23+cu083/0-23+cu081/0-23+cu080/0-23+cu079/0-23
   +cu076/0-23
1091846.mu01            maad-huangy cal-l    Re26Ro01-02       13256     6    144       --   72:00:00 R  32:35:35
   cu200/0-23+cu105/0-23+cu069/0-23+cu068/0-23+cu067/0-23+cu066/0-23
1092285.mu01            maad-zhoukc cal-l    Iso_Driven_Hoff_  30786     6    144       --   72:00:00 R  29:18:04
   cu172/0-23+cu171/0-23+cu164/0-23+cu155/0-23+cu101/0-23+cu100/0-23
1092768.mu01            maad-zhoukc cal-l    Iso_Driven_Hon1E   3271     6    144       --   72:00:00 R  27:35:55
   cu036/0-23+cu035/0-23+cu034/0-23+cu033/0-23+cu032/0-23+cu031/0-23
1092804.mu01            maad-zhoukc cal-l    Iso_Driven_Hon5E   9137     6    144       --   72:00:00 R  27:34:03
   cu030/0-23+cu029/0-23+cu028/0-23+cu027/0-23+cu026/0-23+cu025/0-23
1092805.mu01            maad-leeh   cal-l    DINO               5942    18    432       --   72:00:00 R  27:23:35
   cu084/0-23+cu062/0-23+cu059/0-23+cu058/0-23+cu057/0-23+cu056/0-23+cu052/0-23
   +cu051/0-23+cu048/0-23+cu041/0-23+cu024/0-23+cu022/0-23+cu021/0-23
   +cu016/0-23+cu011/0-23+cu005/0-23+cu004/0-23+cu003/0-23
```

Now I want to confirm  the selected job running on a node.

For example: 
the job 1089608 is running on nodes:

```
cu222/0-23+cu206/0-23+cu191/0-23+cu186/0-23+cu175/0-23+cu163/0-23+cu158/0-23
+cu142/0-23+cu125/0-23+cu124/0-23+cu118/0-23+cu116/0-23+cu115/0-23
+cu114/0-23+cu113/0-23+cu112/0-23+cu111/0-23+cu110/0-23+cu109/0-23
+cu108/0-23+cu089/0-23+cu047/0-23
```

the job 1091846 is running on nodes:

```
cu200/0-23+cu105/0-23+cu069/0-23+cu068/0-23+cu067/0-23+cu066/0-23
```

I have tried:

```
  grep 1091846 JobInfofile | grep cu105
```

The result is wrong, because "1091846" and "cu105" are in different rows.

I have tried anther way:

```
grep -A 1 1091846 JobInfofile | grep cu105
```

It is OK, but it is wrong for:

```
grep -A 1 1089608 JobInfofile | grep cu108
```

Is there a way to confirm the selected node existed between mu01 and mu01?

for example, for the job 1089608, I just care about the nodes content between 1089608.mu01 and 1090225.mu01

Comment: Not clear, please post expected output too in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, though not completely sure. Where `val` is a variable where you could mention value which you want to search.

```
awk -v val="1089608" '
/^[0-9]{7}/{
  flag=""
}
/^[0-9]{7}/ && substr($0,1,7)==val{
  flag=1
  print $1
  next
}
flag
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, this will print out the section for a job if it contains a particular node:

```
$ cat foo.sed
/^1089608\./!d
h
:nodelist
n
/^   / {
  H
  b nodelist
}
g
/\<cu111\>/p
q
$ sed -nf foo.sed foo.txt
1089608.mu01            maad-zhangy cal-l    ct+gd+sdg-160FWH  25025    22    528       --   72:00:00 R  07:20:52
   cu222/0-23+cu206/0-23+cu191/0-23+cu186/0-23+cu175/0-23+cu163/0-23+cu158/0-23
   +cu142/0-23+cu125/0-23+cu124/0-23+cu118/0-23+cu116/0-23+cu115/0-23
   +cu114/0-23+cu113/0-23+cu112/0-23+cu111/0-23+cu110/0-23+cu109/0-23
   +cu108/0-23+cu089/0-23+cu047/0-23
```

Or a `sed` one liner, just because we can:

```
$ sed -n '/^1089608\./!d;h;:a;n;/^   /{;H;ba;};g;/\<cu111\>/p;q' foo.txt
```

This version, in Perl, is less obscure and more maintainable:

```
$ cat foo.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $line = <>;
while (defined($line)) {
    my $job = $line;
    $line = <>;
    while (defined($line) && $line =~ /^   /) {
        $job .= $line;
        $line = <>;
    }
    print $job if $job =~ /^1089608\./ && $job =~ /\bcu111\b/;
}
$ perl -w foo.pl foo.txt
1089608.mu01            maad-zhangy cal-l    ct+gd+sdg-160FWH  25025    22    528       --   72:00:00 R  07:20:52
   cu222/0-23+cu206/0-23+cu191/0-23+cu186/0-23+cu175/0-23+cu163/0-23+cu158/0-23
   +cu142/0-23+cu125/0-23+cu124/0-23+cu118/0-23+cu116/0-23+cu115/0-23
   +cu114/0-23+cu113/0-23+cu112/0-23+cu111/0-23+cu110/0-23+cu109/0-23
   +cu108/0-23+cu089/0-23+cu047/0-23
```

And in Python:

```
import fileinput
import re

lines = fileinput.input()

line = lines.readline()
while line:
    job = line
    line = lines.readline()
    while line and line.startswith('   '):
        job += line
        line = lines.readline()

    if re.match(r'1089608\.', job) and re.search(r'\bcu111\b', job):
        print(job, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\S/h;//b;G;/\n1089608/P' file
```

Store each job in the hold space and for all other lines append the hold space. If the job number matches the one required, print the first line in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk -v job="1089608" '{if (match($0,"mu01")!=0) flag=0; if (flag==1) print;if(match($1,job "\\.mu01")!=0) flag=1}' JobInfofile
```

that searchs lines that matches "job.mu01" when found it, sets flag, so if next line doesn't match "mu01" it prints.